# Unable to get desired out format in R language

Tags: r

Can anyone help me with the format .. what command should I be using or let me know what should I learn to solve this myslef...)

```
> d
[1] 5.5
> cat("##",d[])
## 5.5
[1] 5.5
> print("##",d)
[1] "##"
> print("##",d[])
[1] "##"
> print(d)
[1] 5.5
```

I am looking to match the sample out:

```
## [1] 5.5
```

Comment: I guess `cat("## [1]", d)`?

Comment: `paste("## [1]",sprintf("%.1f", d))`

Comment: thanks all options works! Why just printing d was printing [1] 5.5 then when I use it with cat it not printing [1]?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat(paste("##", capture.output(print(5.5))))
## [1] 5.5
```

There are probably better alternatives to your actual problem (which you don't define). Package knitr comes to mind.